# How to remove an image across all nodes in a Docker swarm?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-image

On the local host, I can remove an image using either `docker image rm` or `docker rmi`.

What if my current host is a manager node in a Docker swarm and I wish to cascade this operation throughout the swarm?

When I first created the Docker service, the image was pulled down on each node in the swarm. Removing the service did not remove the image and all nodes retain a copy of the image.

It feels natural that if there's a way to "push" an image out to all the nodes then there should be an equally natural way to remove them too without having to SSH into every single machine :'( Plus, this is a real problem. Sooner or later the nodes are bound to have no more disk space!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there is no such option as of now. Each node is responsible of its own cleanup. There is a command `docker system prune -f` that you can use to clear container data.

But tagged images can be deleted using `docker rmi` only. See below issues

https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/24079

Answer (score 0):

This is doable. Create host entries in `/etc/hosts` on your manager node, like this

```
1.1.1.1    node01
1.1.1.2    node02
1.1.1.3    node03
```

Then run

```
for i in {01..03}; do ssh node$i "docker rmi $(docker images -q)"; done
```

Warning: this command will remove all images on all nodes, listed in `/etc/hosts`.